# Regression Elasticities in multiple regression with continuous and dummy variables

Tags: regression, econometrics, elasticity

So let's say I have a multiple regression as such:

Y = constant  + a<sub>1</sub>X<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>2</sub>X<sub>2</sub> + a<sub>3</sub>X<sub>3</sub>

Here a<sub>c</sub> is the coeffcient corresponding to the X<sub>c</sub>

- Y is a normal variable
- constant is a non-zero constant
- X<sub>1</sub> is a normal variable
- X<sub>2</sub> is actually a natural log variable, for instance, LN(income per capita)
- X<sub>3</sub> is a 0,1 dummy variable. So it is 1 if a country is, let's say, 
  landlocked, 0  otherwise.

I want to find the elasticities of all my X variables. Now, I know that a log-log regression will give elasticities, without any other need for computation. 
So, I take logs of Y and X<sub>1</sub>, leaving all the other variables untouched. X<sub>2</sub> is already logged and X<sub>3</sub> is unable to be logged since it is 0 at some places. Then I regress:

LN(Y) = constant  + a<sub>l1</sub>LN(X<sub>1</sub>) + a<sub>l2</sub>X<sub>2</sub> + a<sub>l3</sub>X<sub>3</sub>

and the resulting coefficients (a<sub>l1</sub>, a<sub>l2</sub>, a<sub>l3</sub>) are the elasticities. (As an aside, what do the t-stats means here, do elasticities have their own significance?) Is this the correct approach? Or is the only way to get elasticities in such a regression to do it the manual way that is:

- for X<sub>1</sub> elasticity is a<sub>1</sub> * AVG(X<sub>1</sub>) / AVG(Y)
- for X<sub>2</sub> elasticity is a<sub>2</sub> * AVG(X<sub>2</sub>)

And elasticity is meaningless for X<sub>3</sub> since it is a 0-1 variable since a percent change is impossible.

The latter is the classical approach I was taught, but this is far less convenient than the log-log regression and does not give us t-stats. So my question is, is the log-log approach correct? If not, can it be modified to handle the case I'm describing? Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at [this post by David Giles](https://davegiles.blogspot.com/2011/03/dummies-for-dummies.html) for dummy and unlogged x cases.